# React js не приходят данные по axious запросу

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios

Отправляю данные axious'ом на свой сервер, данные(если проверить вручную) приходят. Через axious - нет.
Можете попробовать потестировать через 178.150.137.228:3000/list и 178.150.137.228:5303/users
Вот код компонентов:

Persons:

```
import React from "react";

class Person extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <a href="http://178.150.137.228:5303/register">{this.props.id}</a>
        );
    }
}

export default Person
```

List:

```
import React from "react";
import Person from "./Person";
import axios from 'axios';

class List extends React.Component {

    render() {
        let persons = [];
        axios.get("http://178.150.137.228:5303/users")
            .then(res => {
                var users = Object.values(res.data);
                users.map(function (user) {
                    return <li> <Person id={user.toString()}/> </li>
                });
                console.log(users);
                persons = users;
            })
        return(
            <ul>
                {persons}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default List
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете асинхронный вызов, те в момент когда реакт будет отображать `{person}`, в нем еще ничего не будет. Можно использовать `state` - в него ложим setState'ом то, что пришло через `axios` вот так:

```
state = {
    users: [],
  }

  render() {
    axios.get('http://178.150.137.228:5303/users')
      .then(({data}) => this.setState({users: [...Object.values(data)]}))

    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.users.map(user => (
          <li><Person id={user.toString()} /></li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
```